# no internet on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, internet

i really really hope you can help me here, i just got a 12.04 server set up and running in London and with port changed and ssh [RSA KEY] log in. Then i updated my home pc to 11.10 and cant get connected to the internet. I was going to USB upgrade again to 12.04 but the iso file when booting from pen wants to upgrade using the net for some packages. Bummer.

Some details.

```
jam@jam-desktop:~$ ifconfig -a 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4c:36:07:58   
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B) 
          Interrupt:25 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback   
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35968 (35.9 KB)  TX bytes:35968 (35.9 KB) 

jam@jam-desktop:~$ ifconfig 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback   
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35968 (35.9 KB)  TX bytes:35968 (35.9 KB)
```

I have searched the net widly on this problem for around 3 days now, and about to scream. lol

more details..

Network says plug  UNPLUGGED .. [its not]

In the /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I had been able to force start the connection a few days ago by doing something like.. 
sudo /etc/init.d/network restart ..... or something along them lines. I still not sure what caused it to start but was playing with this at the time when it started, problem was after doing a reboot it cant find the connection again.

I really need all the help i can get on this, i fallen behind on business, were i should have started building my online shop i find i might have to rebuild this pc and the server. Please help.

Comment: `sudo dhclient eth0` helps?

Comment: jam@jam-desktop:~$ sudo dhclient eth0 
[sudo] password for jam: 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists 
jam@jam-desktop:~$        thats what i get.

Comment: And i just noticed the internet is back on by doing that sudo... bla bla..  so if i reboot will i have to enter that again? scared to turn it of now. lol thanks for helping bro, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

InEdit Connectios make sure the Connection Name is Auto(eth0)ie ethzero-MTU is set to automatic-IP v 4 settings are Method: Automatic(DHCP), both boxes are ticked for 1.Require IP4 addressingfor this connection to complete, and2.Available to all users, In IP v 6 settings, make sure Method: is set to Ignore, and tick the box for Available to all users